# InvalidRequestError: Instance '<User at 0x7f65938a7510>' is not persisted

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I want to perform such a test in the framework Flask and gets the message:

```
InvalidRequestError: Instance '<User at 0x7f65938a7510>' is not persisted

  File "tests.py", line 31, in test_removeProfil
    db.session.delete(user)
```

My test code:

```
class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_removeProfil(self):
        user = User(name="John", age=33, email="john@john.com")
        db.session.delete(user)
        db.session.commit()
        self.assertNotEqual(user.name, "John")
        self.assertNotEqual(user.age, 33)
        self.assertNotEqual(user.email, "john@john.com")
```

Answer (score 18):

You are trying to delete a new instance, rather than an instance you got from the database.  Either you meant to use `db.session.add()`, or you meant to use `user  = User.query.filter_by(email='john@john.com').first()` (or something similar) and delete that.

You might also have trouble accessing attributes of the deleted instance (assuming you delete it correctly as above).  When you commit a session, all instances in that session are expired.  Trying to access an expired attribute triggers a database lookup, but there can be no lookup for this object because it was deleted.

You can turn [`expire_on_commit`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.sessionmaker.params.expire_on_commit) off, but that is not the normal behavior and will probably cause you other problems.

You could also try calling [`make_transient`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session.html?highlight=delete#sqlalchemy.orm.session.make_transient) on it.

Ultimately, you should really just abandon instances that have been deleted.  There is probably a better way to do whatever you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 8):

When you call

```
user = User(name="John", age=33, email="john@john.com")
```

you create python object, not object in db. So you need first add it to db

```
db.session.add(user)
db.session.commit()
```

after it you can delete it from db

```
db.session.delete(user)
db.session.commit()
```

and your `assertNotEqual` have no sence.  You should test that result of select from db before and after delete is different

Answer (score 0):

If you add an obj to the session, it will return an error if it is already in the database. The session.rollback() command will help you.

> session.add(obj)

> ```
> try:
>     if commit:
>         session.commit()
> except:
>     session.rollback()
> ```